# Little utility to add element in .config app file

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I need to make a little utility that upgrade an xml .config c# application file outside that application.

I just need to add this element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>

  ...

  ...

  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Which is the easy way?

Comment: Read the file as XML document and add as node.

Comment: [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't now what exacly You want to add, but this is a example

Try like this:

**Source:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    ...

</configuration>
```

**Source Code**  [solution is tested and work as You want]

```
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        xmlDoc.Load("test.xml");

        var startupNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/startup");

        var configuratioNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration");

        if (startupNode == null)
        {
            var newNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("startup");

            newNode.SetAttribute("useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy", "true");

            var secondNewNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("supportedRuntime");

            secondNewNode.SetAttribute("version", "v4.0");
            secondNewNode.SetAttribute("sku", ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2");

            newNode.AppendChild(secondNewNode);

            configuratioNode.AppendChild(newNode);
        }
        else
        {
            var supportedRuntime = startupNode.SelectSingleNode("/supportedRuntime");

            if (supportedRuntime == null)
            {
                var secondNewNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("supportedRuntime");

                secondNewNode.SetAttribute("version", "v4.0");
                secondNewNode.SetAttribute("sku", ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2");

                startupNode.AppendChild(secondNewNode);
            }
        }

        xmlDoc.Save("test.xml");
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  ...

  ...




 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
 </startup>

 </configuration>
```

Comment: Good! This is exactly what I need! Is there a way to check if the 'startup' section with 'supportedRuntime' attribute already exist before trying to add it?

Comment: If in the document already appears something like "<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
"? How can I edit it for replacing with "<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
 </startup>"?

Answer (score 1):

I would use XSLT. Example:

**Source**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <someXml/>
</configuration>
```

**Transformation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="configuration">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
                <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
            </startup>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Target**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <someXml/>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```